# Tune SQL Query-out put weekly average for each performance counter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have some performance data I'm trying to report on.

I need the output to give me averages of each week of the month for each counter.

Here is the query which uses a date/time field (i.e.'2012-01-01 00:00:00.750')

```
SELECT MachineName ,
        CounterName ,
        InstanceName, 
        CounterValue,
        ObjectName,
        CounterDateTime 
FROM    dbo.CounterDetails cdt

        INNER JOIN dbo.CounterData cd ON cdt.CounterID = cd.CounterID
        INNER JOIN DisplayToID d ON d.GUID = cd.GUID

WHERE   MachineName = '\\SERVER1'

AND CounterDateTime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00.750' AND '2012-01-31 23:59:00.750'
GROUP BY ObjectName, CounterName, InstanceName, CounterValue, CounterDateTime, MachineName
ORDER BY CounterDateTime
```

Appreciate replies

Comment: 1. What SQL product and which version thereof are you using? Please add the appropriate tag(s). 2. The column references in your query do not include table aliases. However, it might really help to know which columns belong to which table. 3. It would also be a good idea to specify which column you want the weekly averages on. (I do think it is `CounterValue`, but why make people guess?) 4. Same goes about grouping criteria. Do you want *overall* weekly averages or grouped by `MachineName`? Or by something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, was away and just got back.  1.)SQL Server 2000  2.)will send this on the wknd. 3.)Looking to get averages on each performance counter, and this is the CounterValue column. 4.)First looking to get averages for each CounterValue and then group by MachineName.  Hope this helps, will add more detail on the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your fields as it don't make sense to me, but you can try something this:

```
SELECT  MachineName
        , ObjectName
        , InstanceName
        , CounterName
        , DATEPART( YEAR, CounterDateTime ) As YearNo
        , DATEPART( MONTH, CounterDateTime ) As MonthNo
        , DATEPART( WEEK, CounterDateTime ) AS WeekNo
        , AVG(CounterValue) AS avgCounterValue
FROM    dbo.CounterDetails cdt
        INNER JOIN dbo.CounterData cd
            ON cdt.CounterID = cd.CounterID
        INNER JOIN DisplayToID d
            ON d.GUID = cd.GUID
WHERE       MachineName = '\\SERVER1'
            AND CounterDateTime BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00.750' AND '2012-01-31 23:59:00.750'
GROUP BY    MachineName, ObjectName, InstanceName, CounterName
            , DATEPART( YEAR, CounterDateTime )
            , DATEPART( MONTH, CounterDateTime )
            , DATEPART( WEEK, CounterDateTime )
ORDER BY    MachineName, ObjectName, InstanceName, CounterName
            , DATEPART( YEAR, CounterDateTime )
            , DATEPART( MONTH, CounterDateTime )
            , DATEPART( WEEK, CounterDateTime )
```

If your table is large, you might want to create an index on [MachineName] and [CounterDateTime]

Comment: Thanks, just gave it a try.  Got back Server: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Syntax error converting datetime from character string.